# Implementing scrollable tabs in modal windows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created modal windows that allow tabs, but if there are more tabs than the window, I would like to provide them with scrolling. Created scrolling on the Y-axis has tabs that do not fit into the size of the window. They fall down into rows and thus are hidden; they can scroll respectively, but they jump 2-3 (depending on how many of them in a row). I would like to provide scrolling on X smoothly, for example like Firefox. I do **not** want to use jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="drsMoveHandle" id="title_<?php echo $mwModalId?>" style="display:block;" >
<div class="drsMoveHandleContent active" id = "titleContent_<?php echo $mwModalId?>" title="<?php echo $mwTitleContent?>" style="left:0px;">
    <?php echo $mwTitleContent?>
</div>
```

drsMoveHandle - container for the tabs (one per box)

drsMoveHandleContent  - same tabs (there may be several)

CSS:

```
.drsMoveHandle {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height: 20px;
padding-left:20px;
background-color: #D9D9D9;
cursor: move;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;}

.drsMoveHandleContent {
position:relative;
height: 19px;
float:left;
top:0px;
cursor:alias;
overflow:hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
background-color:#E5E5E5;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-right:1px solid #000;
border-top-left-radius:9px;
border-top-right-radius:9px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
padding-right:15;
padding-left:10;
display:inline-block;}
```

JavaScript:

```
function canselEvent(e){
e = e || window.event;
if(e.preventDefault && e.stopPropagation){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
else {
    e.returnValue = false;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
}
return false;}

function wheel(e) {
e = e || window.event;
var delta = 0;    
if(e.wheelDelta) delta = e.wheelDelta/120;
else if(e.detail) delta = -e.detail/3;
delta *= 20
var scrollDiv = e.target.parentNode || e.srcElement.parentNode;
scrollDiv.scrollTop = scrollDiv.scrollTop - delta;
//scrollDiv.scrollLeft = scrollDiv.scrollLeft - delta;
canselEvent(e);}

function prepareScrollebleDiv(elms) {
var scrollDiv;
for(var i=0; i<elms.length; i++) {
    scrollDiv = document.getElementById(elms[i].id);
    if (scrollDiv.addEventListener) scrollDiv.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    scrollDiv.onmousewheel = wheel;
}}
```

Comment: In this article is my problem: [link]http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-razmestit-dva-sloya-po-gorizontali  - when window become smaller, the second div fall into the next row! I need that div stay in one row

Answer (score 0):

invented solution (if you have a better - write):

CSS:

From:

```
 .drsMoveHandle {
 ...
 width:100%;
 height: 20px;
 padding-left:20px;
 ...}
```

To:

```
.drsMoveHandle {
    ...
    width:2000px;
    left:-1000px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-left:1020px;
    ...
}
```

JavaScript;

need to rewrite the function wheel:

do not need to scroll, you need to change the position of the left:

```
scrollDiv.style.left = parseInt(scrollDiv.style.left) + delta;
```

solution is not the best, but it works.